# Laravel: method parameter bypass

Tags: php, laravel, methods, parameters

In my laravel (7.x) application, I have a method called `_index` in different `controllers & models` with exactly same functionality (fetch the data to display in the grid) and parameters (except 1, that requires an additional parameter called `available`).

So, I created a `super method` in the base controller, something line this:

Controller.php

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    protected function _index($ModelClass, $status, $available = null)
    {
        # models
        $Model = new $ModelClass();

        # accessing and returning method data
        return $Model->_index(status: $status, available: $available);
    }
}
```

SomeController.php

```php
class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function _index()
    {
        # accessing super methods
        $SomeModel = $this->_index(SomeModel::class, true);

        ...

        # rendering
        return view('some-view', compact($SomeModel));
    }
}

class SomeModel extends Model
{
    public function _index($status = null, $available = null) : array
    {
        if($available == true)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

AnotherController.php

```php
class AnotherController extends Controller
{
    public function _index()
    {
        # accessing super methods
        $AnotherModel = $this->_index(AnotherModel::class);

        ...

        # rendering
        return view('another-view', compact($AnotherModel));
    }
}

class AnotherModel extends Model
{
    public function _index($status = null) : array
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Only `SomeController / index` is working fine but other controllers which does not required the `$available` parameter are showing `Unknown named parameter $available`.

Is there a way to ignore the missing parameters, as there is no point in including the parameter in the rest of the methods, throughout the application..?

Comment: The method in your `AnotherController` doesn't use the `$status` parameter

Comment: if available is to be a boolean, why not set the default to false ?

Comment: It doesn't matter if I set the `available` as `false` or `null`. Because the `available` only exists in the `SomeModel`. Also, If I ever need to use the `available` in any other `controller/model` with different datatype then I'll have to make the change in the `BaseController` as well.

Comment: `Controller -> _index` method always instantiate the `Model` class (Some or Another) and calls the `_index` method of that Model class with `$status and $available` but your AnotherModel's `_index` method only takes `$status` whereas you're passing `$available` to it as well so it's throwing error. You'll need to add `$available`  in AnotherModel's `_index` method as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the right way to handle this or not.

Controller.php

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    protected function _index($ModelClass, $status, $available = null)
    {
        # models
        $Model = new $ModelClass();

        try
        {
            # accessing and returning method data
            return $Model->_index(status: $status, available: $available);
        }
        catch (\Throwable $th)
        {
            # handling missing parameter error/exception
            if($th->getMessage() == 'Unknown named parameter $available')
            {
                return $Model->_index(status: $status);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, in case anybody finds a better way to handle this issue. Then do post your answer.

Thanks...